# Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. (undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, discord, discord.js

So I was working on a multiplayer survival type game, and at some point I had 3 message component collectors nested within each other, which lead to the inner most collector just failing. So instead I set it so there is a promise which gets resolved when the outermost collector ends, and I await that, once the promise is resolved we move to creating the next collector and the inner collector, but then it gives an error which was undefined. That without ever going past the promise. Normally I can fix my own errors, but this has thoroughly stumped me.
This is the command which was the multiplayer survival game I was talking about.
https://sourceb.in/ebtBGKmQWQ
[error screenschot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r3xG.png)

SO I had multiple trycatch blocks, the first being the one in the command file. Second was in interactionCreate event.

```
try {
    await command.execute(interaction, client);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(
        `[INTERACTION CREATE] ${error.stack}\n[INTERACTION CREATE] ${
            interaction.user.username
        } used ${interaction.commandName} in ${interaction.channel.name} at ${new Date(
            Date.now()
        )}`.red
    );
    return await interaction
        .reply({
            content: "There was an error while executing this command!",
            ephemeral: true,
        })
        .catch((e) => {});
}
```

Above even that was another trycatch block

```
try {
    //other things
    //the previous trycatch block
} catch (error) {
    console.log(`[INTERACTION CREATE] ${error.stack}\n${new Date(Date.now())}`.red);
}
```

Then in my index.js I had these:

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", (reason, promise) => {
    console.log(
        `[BOT] Unhandled Rejection at ${promise}\n[BOT] Unhandled Rejection reason: ${
            reason.stack
        }\n${new Date(Date.now())}`.red
    );
});

process.on("uncaughtException", (error, origin) => {
    console.log(
        `[BOT] Uncaught Exception at ${origin}\n[BOT] Uncaught Exception error: ${
            error.stack
        }\n${new Date(Date.now())}`.red
    );
});

process.on("uncaughtExceptionMonitor", (error, origin) => {
    console.log(
        `[BOT] Uncaught Exception Monitor at ${origin}\n[BOT] Uncaught Exception Monitor error: ${
            error.stack
        }\n${new Date(Date.now())}`.red
    );
});
```

I also had an error event which console logs the error.stack. But everything kept saying TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stack')
so I put all those in comments and the resulting error is the image included.
As I said, normally I can fix my own mess, but I don't even know where to begin with this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot you sent, somewhere in your code `undefined` is being thrown, and your `uncaughtException` handler is trying to read `(undefined).stack`, leading to an infinite loop of `Cannot read properties from undefined` errors.

After commenting out the `error.stack` property access, you still end up catching `undefined` instead of an actual `Error` object. I have a feeling it's due to all of the nested `try`-`catch` blocks you have, and there's definitely a better way to catch errors when developing Discord bots.

It's not good practice to keep your program running after the `uncaughtException` event is emitted. This isn't my opinion, either. Read the [Node.js docs on 'Using 'uncaughtException' correctly'](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#warning-using-uncaughtexception-correctly). Having *any* exception be uncaught means there is clearly something wrong with your code, and you should let the program exit/crash. However, letting Node crash normally results in some problems for projects like Discord bots, since Discord has no idea the bot crashed, and not freeing up or closing any resources you're using can lead to even more problems.

In my Discord bot projects I handle `uncaughtException` like this:

```js
// Assuming `client` is in scope here.
process.on('uncaughtException', async (err) => {
    // Print the exception
    console.error(err);

    // Send yourself the exception (optional)
    await (await client.application.fetch()).owner.send(`\`\`\`js${err.stack}\`\`\``);

    // Disconnect the bot from Discord
    await client.destroy();

    // Perform other resource cleanup as necessary
    // Disconnect from DBs, close open files, etc.

    // Terminate the process with a nonzero exit code
    process.exit(1);
});
```

Using this approach will guarantee that the first uncaught exception that Node encounters will be brought to your attention, and nothing else. You also don't need to register an `unhandledRejection` listener, as they emit `uncaughtException` events anyway.

Try commenting out all of your `try`-`catch` logic, and use the `uncaughtException` listener above. Let me know how it goes in a comment here.